# Connecting PS4 controller to PC with bluetooth while charging

Tags: technical-issues, pc, controllers, rocket-league

I play rocket league with a ps4 controller on PC and I would like to always use Bluetooth. When my controller battery is low, I would like to plug it into the computer to charge it. When I do that, however, the computer detects the controller as a separate device and so it does not work for the car in rocket league anymore (instead I can use it to add a guest player).

Is there any way to prevent this or perhaps make windows think it is the same controller plugged in as it is over Bluetooth?

Thanks

Comment: Plug in the controller when you're not playing?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the controller should switch between bluetooth and wired automatically but since your saying it doesn't try switching between matches of rocket league so you dont lose your input and turn off your controller first before plugging it in. Let us know if that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback, Nolonar brings up an obvious point but I just discovered that if you plug the controller in while it is on and connected by bluetooth, the computer will charge it without detecting it as a second controller. I must have only ever plugged it in after it died on bluetooth, which is what doesn't work.

Thanks for your input :).

Answer (score 2):

The easier solution might be to disable one port of your computer for data transfers, leaving it as charging only. Better yet, keep a USB charger on your desk to use for such things. I use the same cable/plug I charge my phone with to charge my wireless ps4 controller as well.

I'm not sure how well your suggested solution would work, as you would either need to selectively not make a data connection to some devices sometimes or trick your computer into doing things it doesn't want to. Making the computer think that a Bluetooth controller and USB controller are the exact same device would be incredibly difficult if not outright impossible. It would at least require heavy manual configuration and be very error prone. I can't imagine it being preferable in any way to running a charger from an outlet to where you sit.

Comment: "*The easier solution might be to either* [...]" When you say "either", you're implying that there's at least 2 options to choose from, but I only see 1.

Comment: Sorry, that was a artifact of sloppy message editing. Fixed now.